# Next.js: getServerSideProps and or getInitialProps affecting the page loads

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

When i used `getSeverSideProps` or `getInitialProps` my page is not loading, it keep on loading without displaying the content but when i remove these guys everything works. What is wrong with my code here? **HELP**.

```
...
interface Props {
  data: any;
}

const Home: NextPage<Props> = ({ data }) => {
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  const router = useRouter();

  const [showForm, setShowForm] = React.useState(false);
  const theme = useSelector((state: any) => state.theme);
  const className: string = `${styles.app} ${
    theme === "dark" ? styles.dark__theme : styles.light__theme
  }`;
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      {/* <Header theme="light" /> */}
      <HeaderSkeleton theme={theme} />
      {/* <FormSkeleton theme={theme} /> */}
      {showForm ? <Form theme={theme} setShowForm={setShowForm} /> : null}
      <div className={styles.app__main}>
        <Fleets theme={theme} />
        <FleetsSkeleton theme={theme} />
        <PostSkeleton theme={theme} />
        <PostSkeleton theme={theme} />
        <PostSkeleton theme={theme} />
        <PostSkeleton theme={theme} />
        <PostSkeleton theme={theme} />
        <Post theme={theme} />
        <Post theme={theme} />
        <Post theme={theme} />
        <Post theme={theme} />
      </div>
      <IconButton title="new post" onClick={() => setShowForm(true)}>
        <IoIosCreate className={styles.home__create__post__icon} />
      </IconButton>
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const user = await apolloClient.query({
    query: USER_QUERY,
  });
  if (!user.data?.user) {
    context.res.writeHead(307, { Location: "http://localhost:3000/welcome" });
    return {
      props: {
        data: null,
      },
    };
  }
  return {
    props: {
      data: JSON.stringify(user, null, 2),
    },
  };
}
export default Home;
```

The same happend if i use `getInitialProps`

```
...
Home.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
  const user = await apolloClient.query({
    query: USER_QUERY,
  });
  if (!user.data?.user) {
    context.res.writeHead(307, { Location: "http://localhost:3000/welcome" });
    return {
      data: null,
    };
  }
  return {
    data: JSON.stringify(user, null, 2),
  };
};
export default Home;
```

Comment: when you say it's working, you probably mean you don't get the right user ? These calls are getting you the user data. If you don't have it, then the `prop` carries the `data: null`. However you still need to debug why your server API fails ON SERVER. these calls doesn't get called from clients.

Comment: No i mean I'm the page is keep on refreshing without showing any content. but as soon as i remove getServerSideProps or that getInitialProps then the page is back to normal.

Comment: @crispengari Do you get the expected data from the apollo query?

Comment: Yes I'm able to see the data on the server, when i leave the server to load for long.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of Next.js, you should return `data` inside the `props` property.
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering

```
return {
  props: {
    data: JSON.stringify(user, null, 2)
  }
}
```

Comment: i don't think so.

Comment: That makes sense i've tried that but it's not working either

Comment: Hmm I guess if the page isn't loading is safe to say that there is a problem with his query call.Nevertheless, the `props` will become an issue once the serverSide problem gets resolved.

Comment: Have you tried to add a log after the query call to see if it is stuck?

Comment: i've tried that put no output on the console, the server which im quering data is open and working. i just tested it right now.

Comment: Maybe your manual redirect is causing the problem. Try commenting it or using the [Next.js redirect feature](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering) to redirect.

Comment: I also tried that but I'm still getting the same issue. If I console.log(user) I am getting  this object `{ data: { user: null }, loading: false, networkStatus: 7 }` on the server console. But the browser is not showing anything.

Comment: If you are getting `{ user: null }` then you end up at the redirect `if`.